# How do I keep only the first map and when the game is finished, if you click on the map the game restarts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I havet this codepen: https://codepen.io/sp2012/pen/VwpyWdp . Unfortunately, this code is too advanced for me. The game has three maps. I want to keep only the first map and when the game is finished, if you click on the map the game restarts.

The code follows:

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="game-container-1" class="game-container">

  <div id="map-and-controls">
  <div id="game-map-1" class="game-map">
    <div id="tiles" class="layer"></div>
    <div id="sprites" class="layer"></div>
    <div id="success-msg">Goal reached! Tap the maze to change levels.</div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- controls-->    
  <div id="controls">
    <button id="up"></button>
    <div id="horiz">
       <button id="left"></button>
       <button id="right"></button>
    </div>
     <button id="down"></button>
   </div>
  </div>
    <p id="text-1" class="text">Use cursor keys or buttons to move the marble.</p>
   
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
/*
 * General Styling
 */
body {
  font-family: Calibri;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  text-align: center;
}
body.success  {
  background-color: #b7f0b7;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
/* center everything in game container */
.game-container {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
/*
 * Map screen
 */

.game-map {
  position: relative;
}
/*
 * Output text styles
 */

p {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  
}


/*
 * Map on left, controls on right
 * Adapted for the mobile Medium app
 */
#map-and-controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
/*
 * Controls
 */

#controls {
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
/*
 * Container for right and left buttons
 */
#controls #horiz {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
/* 
 * General button styles
 */
#controls button {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
/*
 * Spacing between horiz buttons
 */
button#right {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
button#left {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/*
 * General button arrow styles
 */
#controls button::before {
  content:'';
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
/*
 * Specific Arrow Styles
 */
button#left::before {
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  left: 10px;
  top: 9px;
}
button#right::before {
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  left: 12px;
  top: 9px;
}
button#up::before {
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
  left: 9px;
  top: 9px;
}
button#down::before {
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #000;
  left: 9px;
  top: 12px;
}
#success-msg {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
}
 body.success #success-msg {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.2 ease;
}



/*
 * Layers and tiles are positioned absolutely
 * within coordinate system of .game-map 
 */
div.layer,
div.layer div {
  position: absolute;
}
/* border for floors and wall */
#tiles div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

/*
 * Default wall and floor styles
 */

.default .floor {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.default .wall {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
/*
 * grassland theme  
 */
.grassland .floor {
  background-color: #7bb76d;
}
.grassland .wall {
  background-color: #806d51;
}
.grassland #player {
 background-color: #b2ccec;
}

/* 
 * dungeon theme
 */
.dungeon .floor {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
.dungeon .wall {
  background-color: #9c649c;
}
.dungeon #player {
 background-color: #ab1431;
}
/*
 * player and goal are slightly smaller than tiles
 */
.player, 
.goal {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform:scale(0.85);
}
/*
 * Goal colors
 */
.goal {
  background-color: #FFD700;
  border: 1px solid #98720b;
}
/*
 *  Player default colors
 */
.player {
  background-color: #90ee90;
  border: 1px solid #008000;
  transition: left 0.2s ease, top 0.2s ease;
}
/*
 * Player wobbles when colliding with wall or border
 */
.player.collide {  
  animation: wobble 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  
}

/* 
 * Wobble animation
 */
@keyframes wobble {
  0% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(1px, 1px); }
  10% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(-1px, -2px); }
  20% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(-3px, 0px); }
  30% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(3px, 2px); }
  40% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(1px, -1px);}
  50% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(-1px, 2px); }
  60% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(-3px, 1px); }
  70% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(3px, 1px); }
  80% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(-1px, -1px); }
  90% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(1px, 2px); }
  100% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(1px, -2px);; }
}
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
let app = {};


(function(context) {

  /*
   *  Build an array of levels.
   *  This will scale better if it is stored in a separate JSON File.
   */
  let levels = [];
  levels[0] = {
    map:[
       [1,1,0,0,1],
       [1,0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,1,1,0],
       [0,0,0,1,0],
       [0,1,0,1,0]
    ],
  
    player:{
        x:0,
        y:4
    },
    goal:{
        x:4,
        y:1
    },
    theme:'default',
  };
  // second level
  levels[1] = {
    map:[
       [1,0,1,1,1,1],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0],
       [0,1,1,1,0,0],
       [0,0,0,1,1,0],
       [0,1,0,1,0,0]
    ],
    theme:'grassland',
    player:{
        x:2,
        y:4
    },
    goal:{
        x:4,
        y:4
    }
   };
  // third level
  levels[2] = {
    map:[
       [1,0,1,0,0,1,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
       [1,0,1,1,0,0,0],
       [1,0,0,1,0,1,0],
       [1,1,0,0,1,0,0]
    ],
    theme:'dungeon',
    player:{
        x:2,
        y:4
    },
    goal:{
        x:6,
        y:4
    }
   };
 

/*
 *  The game object constructor.
 *  @param {String} id - the id of the game container DOM element.
 *  @param {Object} level - the starting level of the game.
 */
function Game(id,level) {
  
  this.el = document.getElementById(id);
  
  // level addition
  this.level_idx = 0;
  
  // establish the basic properties common to all this objects.
  this.tileTypes = ['floor','wall'];
  this.tileDim = 32;
  // inherit the level's properties: map, player start, goal start.
  this.map = level.map;
  
  // level switch
  this.theme = level.theme;
  
  // make a copy of the level's player.
  this.player = {...level.player};
  
  // create a property for the DOM element, to be set later.
  this.player.el = null;
  
  // make a copy of the goal.
  this.goal = {...level.goal};
}

/*
 * Create a tile or sprite <div> element.
 * @param {Number} x - the horizontal coordinate the 2D array.
 * @param {Number} y - the vertical coordinate in the 2D array.
 */
Game.prototype.createEl = function(x,y,type) {
   // create one tile.
  let el = document.createElement('div');
       
  // two class names: one for tile, one or the tile type.
  el.className = type;
  
  // set width and height of tile based on the passed-in dimensions.
  el.style.width = el.style.height = this.tileDim + 'px';
  
  // set left positions based on x coordinate.
  el.style.left = x*this.tileDim + 'px';
  
  // set top position based on y coordinate.
  el.style.top = y*this.tileDim + 'px';
      
  return el;
}

/*
 * Applies the level theme as a class to the game element. 
 * Populates the map by adding tiles and sprites to their respective layers.
 */
Game.prototype.populateMap = function() {
  
  // add theme call
  this.el.className = 'game-container ' + this.theme;

  // make a reference to the tiles layer in the DOM.
  let tiles = this.el.querySelector('#tiles');
  
  // set up our loop to populate the grid.
  for (var y = 0; y < this.map.length; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.map[y].length; ++x) {
      
       let tileCode = this.map[y][x];

        // determine tile type using code
        // index into the tileTypes array using the code.
       let tileType = this.tileTypes[tileCode];
      
       // call the helper function
       let tile = this.createEl(x,y,tileType);
       
       // add to layer
       tiles.appendChild(tile);
    }
  }
}

/*
 * Place the player or goal sprite.
 * @param {String} type - either 'player' or 'goal', used by createEl and becomes DOM ID
 */
Game.prototype.placeSprite = function(type) {
  
  // syntactic sugar
  let x = this[type].x
  
  let y = this[type].y;
  
  // reuse the createTile function
  let sprite  = this.createEl(x,y,type);
  
  sprite.id = type;
  
  // set the border radius of the sprite.
  sprite.style.borderRadius = this.tileDim + 'px';
  
  // get half the difference between tile and sprite.
  
  // grab the layer
  let layer = this.el.querySelector('#sprites');
  
  layer.appendChild(sprite);
  
  return sprite;
}

/*
 * Triggers a collide animation on the player sprite.
 */
Game.prototype.collide = function() {
  this.player.el.className += ' collide';
  
  let obj = this;
  
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  obj.player.el.className = 'player';
  },200);
  
  return 0;
  
};
/*
 * Moves the player sprite left.
 */
Game.prototype.moveLeft = function() {
    // if at the boundary, return
    if (this.player.x == 0) {
        this.collide();
        return;
    }
    // itentify next tile
    let nextTile = this.map[this.player.y][this.player.x-1];
  
    // if next tile is a wall, add collide effect and return
    if (nextTile ==1) {
        this.collide();
        return;
    }
    // change coordinates of player object
    this.player.x -=1;
    // update location of DOM element
    this.updateHoriz();
};
/*
 * Moves the player sprite up.
 */
Game.prototype.moveUp = function() {
  if (this.player.y == 0) {
        // at end: these could be combined
        this.collide();
        return;
  }
      
  let nextTile = this.map[this.player.y-1][this.player.x];
  if (nextTile ==1) {
        this.collide();
        return;
  }
  this.player.y -=1;
  this.updateVert();
  
};
/*
 * Moves the player sprite right.
 */
Game.prototype.moveRight = function()  {
   if (this.player.x == this.map[this.player.y].length-1) {
        this.collide();
        return;
   }
   nextTile = this.map[this.player.y][this.player.x+1];
        
   if (nextTile ==1) {
        this.collide()
        return;
   }
   this.player.x += 1;
   
   this.updateHoriz();
};
/*
 * Moves player sprite down.
 */
Game.prototype.moveDown = function()  {
  if (this.player.y == this.map.length-1) {
        this.collide();
        return;
   }
   // find the next tile in the 2D array.
        
   let nextTile = this.map[this.player.y+1][this.player.x];
    if (nextTile ==1) {
        this.collide()
        return;
   }
   this.player.y += 1;
   this.updateVert();
  
};
/* 
 *  Updates vertical position of player sprite based on object's y coordinates.
 */
Game.prototype.updateVert = function() { 
     this.player.el.style.top = this.player.y * this.tileDim+ 'px';
};
/* 
 *  Updates horizontal position of player sprite based on object's x coordinates.
 */  
Game.prototype.updateHoriz = function() {
     this.player.el.style.left = this.player.x * this.tileDim + 'px'; 
};
/*
 * Moves player based on keyboard cursor presses.
 */
Game.prototype.movePlayer = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    if (event.keyCode < 37 || event.keyCode > 40) {
      return;
    }

    switch (event.keyCode) { 
      case 37:
      this.moveLeft();
      break;
      
      case 38:       
      this.moveUp();
      break;

      case 39:
      this.moveRight();
      break;
        
      case 40:
      this.moveDown();
      break;
    }
 }
/*
 * Check on whether goal has been reached.
 */
Game.prototype.checkGoal = function() {
     let body = document.querySelector('body');
  
     if (this.player.y == this.goal.y &&
       this.player.x == this.goal.x) {
       
       body.className = 'success';
     }
     else {
       body.className = '';
     }
}
/*
 * Changes the level of the game object.
 */
Game.prototype.changeLevel = function() {
    
    // update the level index.
    this.level_idx ++;

    // if higher than max index, set back to zero.
       if (this.level_idx > levels.length -1) {
         this.level_idx = 0;
    }
    
    // get the level at this index.
    let level = levels[this.level_idx];
    
    // sync the map with the level map.
    this.map = level.map;
    // sync the theme with the level theme.
    this.theme = level.theme;

    // make a copy of the level's player object, since x and y change during the game.
    this.player = {...level.player};

    // make a copy of the level's goal object, since x and y change between levels.
    this.goal = {...level.goal};
 }

 /*
  * If goal has been reached, 
  */
 Game.prototype.addMazeListener = function() {

   // grab the map

   let map = this.el.querySelector('.game-map');

   // grab reference to game object since we are going into a function 
   // and "this" will no longer refer to the game object

   let obj = this;

   // if game board is clicked or tapped, see if we should change levels
   map.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) {
     
       // if not at the goal, then get outta here
       if (obj.player.y != obj.goal.y ||
       obj.player.x != obj.goal.x) {
         return;
       }
       // change level of game object by changing it's properties
       obj.changeLevel();
       
       // get the two layers
       let layers = obj.el.querySelectorAll('.layer');
      
       // clear tiles and sprites from layers
       for (layer of layers) {
           layer.innerHTML = '';
       }
       
       // place the new level.
       obj.placeLevel();
     
       // check the goal to reset the message.
       obj.checkGoal();
      
   });
 };

/*
 *  Responds to a keydown event by moving the player and checking the goal.
 */
Game.prototype.keyboardListener = function() {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
      this.movePlayer(event);
      this.checkGoal();
  });
  
 }
 /*
  * Adds mouse down listeners to buttons
  */
 Game.prototype.buttonListeners = function() {
   let up = document.getElementById('up');
   let left = document.getElementById('left');
   let down = document.getElementById('down')
   let right = document.getElementById('right');
   
   // the sprite is out of date
   let obj = this;
   up.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
  
     obj.moveUp();
     obj.checkGoal();   
   });
    down.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
     obj.moveDown();
     obj.checkGoal();   
   });
    left.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
     obj.moveLeft();
     obj.checkGoal();   
   });
    right.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
     obj.moveRight();
     obj.checkGoal();   
   });
   
 }
  
/*
 * Sets the message of the text element.
 * @param {String} msg - The message to be printed.
 */
 Game.prototype.setMessage = function(msg) { 
   let text_el = this.el.querySelector('.text');
   text_el.textContent = msg;
 };

 /*
  * Sizes up the map based on array dimensions.
  */
 Game.prototype.sizeUp = function() {
  
  // inner container so that text can be below it
  let map  = this.el.querySelector('.game-map');
  
  // inner container, height. Need this.map
  map.style.height = this.map.length * this.tileDim + 'px';
   
  map.style.width = this.map[0].length * this.tileDim + 'px';
   
};
  

/*
 * Populates the map.
 * Sizes up the map based on array dimensions.
 * Gives the goal and player some references.
 */ 
 Game.prototype.placeLevel = function() {
    this.populateMap();
    
    this.sizeUp();
   
    this.placeSprite('goal');
    
    // we want the DOM element that gets returned...
    let playerSprite = this.placeSprite('player');
   
    // ..so we can store it in the playerSprite element.
    this.player.el = playerSprite;
   
 }
 /*
  *  Add keyboard, button, and maze tap listeners
  */
 Game.prototype.addListeners = function() {
    
    this.keyboardListener();
    
    this.buttonListeners();
    
    // changing levels
    this.addMazeListener();
  }
  
  /*
   *  Initialization function called once
   */
  context.init = function () {
    
    let myGame = new Game('game-container-1',levels[0]);
    
    // encapsulate for multi-level
    myGame.placeLevel();
    
    // add listeners
    myGame.addListeners();
    
  }
})(app);

/*
 * Tell app to activate the init() function.
 */

app.init();
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Remove the second and third levels from the object or just comment them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment out the second and third level section of the levels[0] object (maps). Change the HTML content that makes reference to other levels.

```js
let app = {};


(function(context) {

  /*
   *  Build an array of levels.
   *  This will scale better if it is stored in a separate JSON File.
   */
  let levels = [];
  levels[0] = {
    map:[
       [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],
       [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1],
       [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
       [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1]
    ],
  
    player:{
        x:0,
        y:0
    },
    goal:{
        x:7,
        y:4
    },
    theme:'default',
  };
  /* second level
  levels[1] = {
    map:[
       [1,0,1,1,1,1],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0],
       [0,1,1,1,0,0],
       [0,0,0,1,1,0],
       [0,1,0,1,0,0]
    ],
    theme:'grassland',
    player:{
        x:2,
        y:4
    },
    goal:{
        x:4,
        y:4
    }
   };
  // third level
  levels[2] = {
    map:[
       [1,0,1,0,0,1,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
       [1,0,1,1,0,0,0],
       [1,0,0,1,0,1,0],
       [1,1,0,0,1,0,0]
    ],
    theme:'dungeon',
    player:{
        x:2,
        y:4
    },
    goal:{
        x:6,
        y:4
    }
   };
 

/*
 *  The game object constructor.
 *  @param {String} id - the id of the game container DOM element.
 *  @param {Object} level - the starting level of the game.
 */
function Game(id,level) {
  
  this.el = document.getElementById(id);
  
  // level addition
  this.level_idx = 0;
  
  // establish the basic properties common to all this objects.
  this.tileTypes = ['floor','wall'];
  this.tileDim = 32;
  // inherit the level's properties: map, player start, goal start.
  this.map = level.map;
  
  // level switch
  this.theme = level.theme;
  
  // make a copy of the level's player.
  this.player = {...level.player};
  
  // create a property for the DOM element, to be set later.
  this.player.el = null;
  
  // make a copy of the goal.
  this.goal = {...level.goal};
}

/*
 * Create a tile or sprite <div> element.
 * @param {Number} x - the horizontal coordinate the 2D array.
 * @param {Number} y - the vertical coordinate in the 2D array.
 */
Game.prototype.createEl = function(x,y,type) {
   // create one tile.
  let el = document.createElement('div');
       
  // two class names: one for tile, one or the tile type.
  el.className = type;
  
  // set width and height of tile based on the passed-in dimensions.
  el.style.width = el.style.height = this.tileDim + 'px';
  
  // set left positions based on x coordinate.
  el.style.left = x*this.tileDim + 'px';
  
  // set top position based on y coordinate.
  el.style.top = y*this.tileDim + 'px';
      
  return el;
}

/*
 * Applies the level theme as a class to the game element. 
 * Populates the map by adding tiles and sprites to their respective layers.
 */
Game.prototype.populateMap = function() {
  
  // add theme call
  this.el.className = 'game-container ' + this.theme;

  // make a reference to the tiles layer in the DOM.
  let tiles = this.el.querySelector('#tiles');
  
  // set up our loop to populate the grid.
  for (var y = 0; y < this.map.length; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.map[y].length; ++x) {
      
       let tileCode = this.map[y][x];

        // determine tile type using code
        // index into the tileTypes array using the code.
       let tileType = this.tileTypes[tileCode];
      
       // call the helper function
       let tile = this.createEl(x,y,tileType);
       
       // add to layer
       tiles.appendChild(tile);
    }
  }
}

/*
 * Place the player or goal sprite.
 * @param {String} type - either 'player' or 'goal', used by createEl and becomes DOM ID
 */
Game.prototype.placeSprite = function(type) {
  
  // syntactic sugar
  let x = this[type].x
  
  let y = this[type].y;
  
  // reuse the createTile function
  let sprite  = this.createEl(x,y,type);
  
  sprite.id = type;
  
  // set the border radius of the sprite.
  sprite.style.borderRadius = this.tileDim + 'px';
  
  // get half the difference between tile and sprite.
  
  // grab the layer
  let layer = this.el.querySelector('#sprites');
  
  layer.appendChild(sprite);
  
  return sprite;
}

/*
 * Triggers a collide animation on the player sprite.
 */
Game.prototype.collide = function() {
  this.player.el.className += ' collide';
  
  let obj = this;
  
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  obj.player.el.className = 'player';
  },200);
  
  return 0;
  
};
/*
 * Moves the player sprite left.
 */
Game.prototype.moveLeft = function() {
    // if at the boundary, return
    if (this.player.x == 0) {
        this.collide();
        return;
    }
    // itentify next tile
    let nextTile = this.map[this.player.y][this.player.x-1];
  
    // if next tile is a wall, add collide effect and return
    if (nextTile ==1) {
        this.collide();
        return;
    }
    // change coordinates of player object
    this.player.x -=1;
    // update location of DOM element
    this.updateHoriz();
};
/*
 * Moves the player sprite up.
 */
Game.prototype.moveUp = function() {
  if (this.player.y == 0) {
        // at end: these could be combined
        this.collide();
        return;
  }
      
  let nextTile = this.map[this.player.y-1][this.player.x];
  if (nextTile ==1) {
        this.collide();
        return;
  }
  this.player.y -=1;
  this.updateVert();
  
};
/*
 * Moves the player sprite right.
 */
Game.prototype.moveRight = function()  {
   if (this.player.x == this.map[this.player.y].length-1) {
        this.collide();
        return;
   }
   nextTile = this.map[this.player.y][this.player.x+1];
        
   if (nextTile ==1) {
        this.collide()
        return;
   }
   this.player.x += 1;
   
   this.updateHoriz();
};
/*
 * Moves player sprite down.
 */
Game.prototype.moveDown = function()  {
  if (this.player.y == this.map.length-1) {
        this.collide();
        return;
   }
   // find the next tile in the 2D array.
        
   let nextTile = this.map[this.player.y+1][this.player.x];
    if (nextTile ==1) {
        this.collide()
        return;
   }
   this.player.y += 1;
   this.updateVert();
  
};
/* 
 *  Updates vertical position of player sprite based on object's y coordinates.
 */
Game.prototype.updateVert = function() { 
     this.player.el.style.top = this.player.y * this.tileDim+ 'px';
};
/* 
 *  Updates horizontal position of player sprite based on object's x coordinates.
 */  
Game.prototype.updateHoriz = function() {
     this.player.el.style.left = this.player.x * this.tileDim + 'px'; 
};
/*
 * Moves player based on keyboard cursor presses.
 */
Game.prototype.movePlayer = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    if (event.keyCode < 37 || event.keyCode > 40) {
      return;
    }

    switch (event.keyCode) { 
      case 37:
      this.moveLeft();
      break;
      
      case 38:       
      this.moveUp();
      break;

      case 39:
      this.moveRight();
      break;
        
      case 40:
      this.moveDown();
      break;
    }
 }
/*
 * Check on whether goal has been reached.
 */
Game.prototype.checkGoal = function() {
     let body = document.querySelector('body');
  
     if (this.player.y == this.goal.y &&
       this.player.x == this.goal.x) {
       
       body.className = 'success';
     }
     else {
       body.className = '';
     }
}
/*
 * Changes the level of the game object.
 */
Game.prototype.changeLevel = function() {
    
    // update the level index.
    this.level_idx ++;

    // if higher than max index, set back to zero.
       if (this.level_idx > levels.length -1) {
         this.level_idx = 0;
    }
    
    // get the level at this index.
    let level = levels[this.level_idx];
    
    // sync the map with the level map.
    this.map = level.map;
    // sync the theme with the level theme.
    this.theme = level.theme;

    // make a copy of the level's player object, since x and y change during the game.
    this.player = {...level.player};

    // make a copy of the level's goal object, since x and y change between levels.
    this.goal = {...level.goal};
 }

 /*
  * If goal has been reached, 
  */
 Game.prototype.addMazeListener = function() {

   // grab the map

   let map = this.el.querySelector('.game-map');

   // grab reference to game object since we are going into a function 
   // and "this" will no longer refer to the game object

   let obj = this;

   // if game board is clicked or tapped, see if we should change levels
   map.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) {
     
       // if not at the goal, then get outta here
       if (obj.player.y != obj.goal.y ||
       obj.player.x != obj.goal.x) {
         return;
       }
       // change level of game object by changing it's properties
       obj.changeLevel();
       
       // get the two layers
       let layers = obj.el.querySelectorAll('.layer');
      
       // clear tiles and sprites from layers
       for (layer of layers) {
           layer.innerHTML = '';
       }
       
       // place the new level.
       obj.placeLevel();
     
       // check the goal to reset the message.
       obj.checkGoal();
      
   });
 };

/*
 *  Responds to a keydown event by moving the player and checking the goal.
 */
Game.prototype.keyboardListener = function() {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
      this.movePlayer(event);
      this.checkGoal();
  });
  
 }
 /*
  * Adds mouse down listeners to buttons
  */
 Game.prototype.buttonListeners = function() {
   let up = document.getElementById('up');
   let left = document.getElementById('left');
   let down = document.getElementById('down')
   let right = document.getElementById('right');
   
   // the sprite is out of date
   let obj = this;
   up.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
  
     obj.moveUp();
     obj.checkGoal();   
   });
    down.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
     obj.moveDown();
     obj.checkGoal();   
   });
    left.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
     obj.moveLeft();
     obj.checkGoal();   
   });
    right.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
     obj.moveRight();
     obj.checkGoal();   
   });
   
 }
  
/*
 * Sets the message of the text element.
 * @param {String} msg - The message to be printed.
 */
 Game.prototype.setMessage = function(msg) { 
   let text_el = this.el.querySelector('.text');
   text_el.textContent = msg;
 };

 /*
  * Sizes up the map based on array dimensions.
  */
 Game.prototype.sizeUp = function() {
  
  // inner container so that text can be below it
  let map  = this.el.querySelector('.game-map');
  
  // inner container, height. Need this.map
  map.style.height = this.map.length * this.tileDim + 'px';
   
  map.style.width = this.map[0].length * this.tileDim + 'px';
   
};
  

/*
 * Populates the map.
 * Sizes up the map based on array dimensions.
 * Gives the goal and player some references.
 */ 
 Game.prototype.placeLevel = function() {
    this.populateMap();
    
    this.sizeUp();
   
    this.placeSprite('goal');
    
    // we want the DOM element that gets returned...
    let playerSprite = this.placeSprite('player');
   
    // ..so we can store it in the playerSprite element.
    this.player.el = playerSprite;
   
 }
 /*
  *  Add keyboard, button, and maze tap listeners
  */
 Game.prototype.addListeners = function() {
    
    this.keyboardListener();
    
    this.buttonListeners();
    
    // changing levels
    this.addMazeListener();
  }
  
  /*
   *  Initialization function called once
   */
  context.init = function () {
    
    let myGame = new Game('game-container-1',levels[0]);
    
    // encapsulate for multi-level
    myGame.placeLevel();
    
    // add listeners
    myGame.addListeners();
    
  }
})(app);

/*
 * Tell app to activate the init() function.
 */

app.init();
```

```css
/*
 * General Styling
 */
body {
  font-family: Calibri;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  text-align: center;
}
body.success  {
  background-color: #b7f0b7;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
/* center everything in game container */
.game-container {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
/*
 * Map screen
 */

.game-map {
  position: relative;
}
/*
 * Output text styles
 */

p {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  
}


/*
 * Map on left, controls on right
 * Adapted for the mobile Medium app
 */
#map-and-controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
/*
 * Controls
 */

#controls {
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
/*
 * Container for right and left buttons
 */
#controls #horiz {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
/* 
 * General button styles
 */
#controls button {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
/*
 * Spacing between horiz buttons
 */
button#right {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
button#left {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/*
 * General button arrow styles
 */
#controls button::before {
  content:'';
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
/*
 * Specific Arrow Styles
 */
button#left::before {
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  left: 10px;
  top: 9px;
}
button#right::before {
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  left: 12px;
  top: 9px;
}
button#up::before {
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
  left: 9px;
  top: 9px;
}
button#down::before {
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #000;
  left: 9px;
  top: 12px;
}
#success-msg {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
}
 body.success #success-msg {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.2 ease;
}



/*
 * Layers and tiles are positioned absolutely
 * within coordinate system of .game-map 
 */
div.layer,
div.layer div {
  position: absolute;
}
/* border for floors and wall */
#tiles div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

/*
 * Default wall and floor styles
 */

.default .floor {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.default .wall {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
/*
 * grassland theme  
 */
.grassland .floor {
  background-color: #7bb76d;
}
.grassland .wall {
  background-color: #806d51;
}
.grassland #player {
 background-color: #b2ccec;
}

/* 
 * dungeon theme
 */
.dungeon .floor {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
.dungeon .wall {
  background-color: #9c649c;
}
.dungeon #player {
 background-color: #ab1431;
}
/*
 * player and goal are slightly smaller than tiles
 */
.player, 
.goal {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform:scale(0.85);
}
/*
 * Goal colors
 */
.goal {
  background-color: #FFD700;
  border: 1px solid #98720b;
}
/*
 *  Player default colors
 */
.player {
  background-color: #90ee90;
  border: 1px solid #008000;
  transition: left 0.2s ease, top 0.2s ease;
}
/*
 * Player wobbles when colliding with wall or border
 */
.player.collide {  
  animation: wobble 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  
}

/* 
 * Wobble animation
 */
@keyframes wobble {
  0% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(1px, 1px); }
  10% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(-1px, -2px); }
  20% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(-3px, 0px); }
  30% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(3px, 2px); }
  40% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(1px, -1px);}
  50% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(-1px, 2px); }
  60% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(-3px, 1px); }
  70% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(3px, 1px); }
  80% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(-1px, -1px); }
  90% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(1px, 2px); }
  100% { transform: scale(0.85) translate(1px, -2px);; }
}
```

```html
<div id="game-container-1" class="game-container">

  <div id="map-and-controls">
  <div id="game-map-1" class="game-map">
    <div id="tiles" class="layer"></div>
    <div id="sprites" class="layer"></div>
    <div id="success-msg">Goal reached! Tap the maze to play again.</div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- controls-->    
  <div id="controls">
    <button id="up"></button>
    <div id="horiz">
       <button id="left"></button>
       <button id="right"></button>
    </div>
     <button id="down"></button>
   </div>
  </div>
    <p id="text-1" class="text">Use cursor keys or buttons to move the marble.</p>
   
</div>
```